# Which pins are power which pins are output?

Tags: connector

We have an accelerometer here are the specs:
http://www.myhoskin.com/newsletters/PDF/7596A.pdf

It has lemo plug but I cant find which pins are for DC power input and which are for output.

The lemo looks like this: http://www.trammicrophones.com/images/equipment/tram/4lemo_pins.jpg

Is there a way to know this without cutting the cable?

Comment: Isn't there a datasheet available?

Comment: there's picture that references the color of the wire and the pin function on the data sheet.

Comment: yes but I dont want to cut to see the colors and which pins are connected to which wires. isnt it possible to know without damaging the cable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you'll have to remove the back-shell of the Lemo and check the colour codes as per this: -

[image]

Comment: so there is no other way then to damage? :(

Comment: The backshell on the lemo can be removed exposing the wires and therefore the colours of the wires and you can see which pins on the lemo these go to.

Comment: The Lemo connectors I've used can be easily dis-assembled and re-assembled without damaging the cable.